# Naming and writing about an LLC proper comma use

Tags: commas, comma-splices

So when filing with the state the long argued debate of using a comma before LLC or not has essentially been settled. The answer being it doesn’t matter AT ALL and in fact some attorneys have always recommended to omit the comma.

My question is when writing the name of an LLC, should you use a comma before LLC? I am asking for grammar as I have heard arguments from both sides. I have also heard since LLC is a initialism that you wouldn’t.

Is this sort of like the semi colon? There is never a need but you can use it?

Comment: Who is LLC? The first rule of communication is to avoid acronyms like the plague, never use them in titles, and define them if you absolutely have to use them. The second rule is not to assume that your audience will know what you are talking about. “When filing with the state” is completely incomprehensible to me. What are you filing? Your finger nails? And the first rule for new users of this site is to finish the [Tour]. And the second is to read the help on asking questions before doing so. Then we can help you.

Comment: Since LLCs have the choice of comma or not, best to copy each one's choice. If burdensome, I'd choose the standard...after I figured out which that is.

Comment: Which style guides did you check? What did they say? (This is more of a writing style question than a grammar one, but other guides--dealing specifically with grammar, punctuation, etc.--might address it, too. In any case, you should check some other sources before asking here.)

Comment: I just realized this isn't about style or grammar.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A limited liability company is a type of company organization in some countries including the United States. It is often abbreviated **LLC**.

Do be aware that [consistency is vital](https://legalbeagle.com/12715711-does-a-comma-go-in-front-of-llc.html.), once you make the choice of how to register your company:

> The important question involves your LLC's legal name. When you file
> to register your LLC as a recognized organization in your state, every
> digit -- whether letter, number or punctuation -- is critical. Your
> state will approve your company name exactly as written. Therefore, if
> you include a comma before "LLC" in your name, it will get approval in
> that format. Omitting a comma will generate approval devoid of
> punctuation. 
> Whether you decide to include or omit a comma before the "LLC," write your company name the same way every time to avoid facing the necessity of re-registering your company because of a punctuation error. For example, ABC Company, LLC is a different entity than ABC Company LLC.

AP Style Guide strongly recommends that a comma should **not** appear before LLC. A comma before LLC is not a requirement in any state LLC registration.

EDIT: I re-read the question, which is:

> My question is when writing the name of an LLC, should you use a comma
> before LLC?

**You should use whatever the LLC owners have chosen to register it as.** This isn't a matter of grammar, but of law.

Comment: 'You should use whatever the LLC owners have chosen to register it as. This isn't a matter of grammar, but of law.' Which is why such questions are off-topic here, Ellie.

Comment: It is indeed true that once a business is already in existence, one's hands may be tied, at least in the contexts that have legal significance. The quoted paragraph from the legalbeagle site, however leaves it entirely open whether one should use a comma or not at the point of staring the business and deciding on its name.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I know. I realized that AFTER I wrote the answer. See my comment on the question. I wrote that after I wrote the answer and the EDIT part. By the time I realized, and was going to suggest closing the question, it was already closed.